# Calculating specific average

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a log with a long variable string and I am trying to get min, max and average from a number.

String examples

```
date time from Time: 100 ms to status code: 
date time Time: 1050 ms status code IP
date time IP Time: 2 ms status code destination
```

"Time: * ms" is constant in every line but the field location is changing.
I would need that ms number max, min and average.

Comment: [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you with that. Also add the expected output.

Comment: Don't you think that that those 3 lines are reporting 3 different things? I mean, getting some average on those may not give you anything meaningful. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 6):

Using GNU awk for the [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-gawk-41) (*"A regular expression (as a string) that tells gawk to create the fields based on text that matches the regular expression.*"):

```
awk -v FPAT='Time:[[:blank:][:digit:]]+ms' '
          { split($1, tmp); sum+=tmp[2] }
NR==1     { min=max=tmp[2] }
min>tmp[2]{ min=tmp[2] }
max<tmp[2]{ max=tmp[2] }

END{ print min, max, sum/NR }' infile
```

Output;

```
2 1050 384
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to loop through all of the fields in each line, get the field number of "ms" and subtract one from that field number, which would give you the field number of your number. As long as the number is always the field before ms, which I think is what you said, then this will work.

Here is an example of printing each number.
`awk '{for(i-1;i<=NF;++i){if($i == "ms"){print $(i-1)}}}' filename`

If you want to get the min, max, and average of the numbers then you will have to do some more stuff.

```
awk '
{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
  if($i == "ms")
    {
     if(NR == 1)
      {min=max=$(i-1)};
     if($(i-1) > max)
      {max=$(i-1)};
     if($(i-1)<min)
      {min=$(i-1)};
     sum=sum+$(i-1);
     count+=1;
    }
  }
}
END{
  average=sum/count;
  print "min: "min;
  print "max: "max;
  print "sum: "sum;
  print "average: "average;
}
```

Output:

```
min: 2
max: 1050
sum: 1152
average: 384
```

Answer (score 0):

With **awk** we first fish out the number of milliseconds from each record, coerce it
to numeric, and update the running sum.

```
awk '
  p=match($0, /Time: [0-9]+ ms/){
    sum += ms = substr($0,p+6,RLENGTH-9)+0
  }
  ms>max{max=ms}
  min==""||ms<min{min=ms}
  END{print min, max, sum/NR}
' file
```

**Output**

```
2 1050 384
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to computing the stats for the time is shown using the desk calculator **dc** utility and the GNU grep with PCRE mode to feed the milliseconds to dc on its main stack, which then computes the minimum, maximum of the stack numbers and also their sum total.

```
if=logfile
ms=$(grep -oP 'Time:\s\K\d+(?=\sms)' < "$if")
dc <<eof
2k $ms
[sM0]sa [sm0]sb
[ddlM<a s0 ddlm>b s0 ls+ss z0<c]sc
[lmn32an lMn32an lsln/n10an]sp
zsn dd sm sM ss z0<c lpx
eof
```

**Output:**

```
2 1050 384.00
```

---

We use match-time code evaluation `(?{code})` , as all lines contain the said regex, to compute the stats (min/max/sum) within the regex itself.
And finally at the eof print the stats .

```
perl -lne '$,=" ";
  m{Time:\h(\d+)\hms(?{
    $1>($M//=$1) and $M=$1;
    $1<($m//=$1) and $m=$1;
    $s += $1})}}{print $m, $M, $s/$.
' logfile
```

**Output**

```
2 1050 384
```

Answer (score -1):

command

Max value:

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /ms/){print $(i-1)}}}' filename| awk 'NR==1{sum=$1}($1 > sum){sum=$1}END {print sum}'
```

output

```
1050
```

Min value:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /ms/){print $(i-1)}}}' filename| awk 'NR==1{sum=$1}($1 < sum){sum=$1}END {print sum}'
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: "Sum" seems like an odd choice of name for a variable that holds either a min or max value and never an actual sum.

Comment: You don't need 2 separate awk scripts and a pipe just to do a min/max/ave calculation. Your code would also fail if the word `films`, for example, appeared in the input since that (and many other words obviously) would match the regexp `/ms/`.